# office-ui-fabric-react: loadTheme to change global CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, themes, office-ui-fabric

I'm using office-ui-fabric-react for my app, and I'm using the `loadTheme` to customize the color palette of my app.

Using `loadTheme` does change how my components behave but it doesn't affect the page's global CSS, like page background etc...
Given the fact that I also import the `office-ui-fabric` dist CSS, I would expect the CSS to be changed too, maybe through some CSS3 variables.

Is this not how it's supposed to work? should I set CSS manually on every `loadTheme` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered this on our Github page, but wanted to toss it in here too:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/5713

loadTheme only updates the theme object passed down to each component. It doesn't add any css to the page. This is very intentional.